# Google Cloud Print setup on DSM 3.2 Synology Disk Station

Tags: printing, cloud, nas

How can you setup Google Cloud Print on a Synology Disk Station running the DSM (Disk Station Manager) version 3.2. On the feature list from Synology it is mentioned, but I can't find the package URL. Is it easy to setup and does it run well?

Comment: Tried it myself and it only works (cloudprinting) when my computer is on. As soon as I shut down my PC no more printing through Clousprint. Very weird. Are there some Firewall settings to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No additional packages are required. Cloud print can be enabled in the External Devices control panel on the Set Up Printer dialog box.

That said, I'm having trouble getting it working myself.